# Event are disabled after the zoom of it's parent div changed

Tags: kineticjs

Using KineticJS, I found that after the zoom ratio of the parent div, the event placed in the canvas is disabled.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mxh42/

Please see the situation here.

First, you can move your mouse on the red circle. Then the popup will show.
Then, please push the button to make the circle small. Then, again you can move your mouse to the new small circle. You will see nothing happens.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap" style="width:200px;height:200px">
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="make it 50%" onClick="document.getElementById('container').style.zoom = '0.5';">
```

JS

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x: 100,
    y: 100
});

var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext();
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
    }
});

arc.on('mouseover', function() {
    alert("mouseover detected");
});

layer.add(arc);
stage.add(layer);
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: try re-drawing the stage.

Comment: also, you might want to use .setScale() rather than built in zoom style as kineticjs may override some styling functionality.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so muuuuuuuuuuch"

Answer (score 0):

so, as put in the comments:

```
stage.draw() // will redraw your stage and could help you out
```

as for zooming:

```
stage.setScale(x,y); //will do all your zooming for you at no loss of functionality
```

and my personal favorite:

```
stage.transitionTo({  //this will animate the zoom
     scale: {x: number, y: number},  //scale by some amount, you need x and y in an objet, not like with .setScale(x,y) where they are integers separated by a comma
     duration: 2  //duration is the amount of time the animation takes (in seconds, not milliseconds)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mxh42/5/